# how can I add an hour to a date variable

Tags: php, date, shift

I have a variable stored in the database which marks the time a user starts a shift, for exapmle, it might look like this 03:05, because I have date("H:i"); how can I just add an hour to the variable that is being pulled from the database? This is the code I have.

```
        $sid = $_SESSION["shift_id"];
        $new_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `shifts` WHERE `shift_id` = '$sid'");
        $new_row = mysql_fetch_Assoc($new_query);
        $check_start = $new_row["start"];
        $over = $check_start + 3600; 
        if($check_start > $over)
        {

            echo "Your shift is complete.";

        }else
        {

            echo "<br />The time will be :<b>$over</b> when your shift is over.<br />";

        }
```

but that doesnt add an hour, so how can I add an hour to what I have?

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Here is a good [tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ) for PDO.

Answer (score 1):

one option, do it in the query:

```
$new_query = mysql_query("SELECT start + INTERVAL 1 HOUR as NEW_START, shifts.* FROM shifts WHERE shift_id = '$sid'");
```

Answer (score 0):

change $over in echo with

```
date('H:i', $over)
```

http://www.php.net/time
and use php enclosure

```
echo "<br />The time will be :<b>".date('H:i', $over)."</b> when your shift is over.<br />";
```

instead

```
echo "<br />The time will be :<b>$over</b> when your shift is over.<br />";
```

**UPDATE:**
if you having problem with the result, maybe you can convert your start into date format before use my code

```
$over = strtotime($check_start) + 3600;
```

http://php.net/strtotime

Comment: I started my "shift" at 03:05 and when I do $over = $check_start + 3600; I don't get 04:05, all I want to do is make it output 04:05 in this example, because that would be the start time + 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're treating time in seconds so you can just explode the row start like this

```
$check_start = $new_row["start"];
$hora = explode(':', $check_start);
$check_start = ($hora[0] * 3600) + ($hora[1] * 60);
$over = $check_start + 3600;
```

At this point you have a check_start numeric in seconds, but your code never will enter to the "Shift complete" part, because you're always adding 3600 to the variable in the conditional

So $check_start > $over will never be TRUE